# Azure tutorial - How to use local blob storage

Tags: windows, azure, cloud

I am new to Windows Azure world. I do not have live Azure account. Can I still do the development work using local blob storage, SQL Azure, Fabric etc?

Can anybody share any link for Azure videos for begineer? I am looking for step by step guide.

Atul Sureka

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your first question. Yes you can. Just download the SDK from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/sdk/) and get started without an account.

You can find a video of how to use blob storage [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/smarx/Windows-Azure-Blob-Storage) as well as other video tutorials.
If you want a text version of how to use Azure Blob Storage you can find it [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2153.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

There's a free trial for Azure: http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/free-trial/

You'll find the Azure SDK includes an emulator for table and Blob storage. It doesn't include an emulator for SQL Azure, however, as it's close enough to full SQL Server that almost all applications will work without drastic changes.

The link above also includes a vast range of documentation and tutorials.